# SAGA Raster Calculator in QGIS Graphical Modeller not subtracting

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, saga

I am using QGIS 2.8.1 to build a model. All is working fine until the raster calculator input. I understand that the raster calculator in QGIS Modeller is a SAGA tool. With this, I have tried both the following formulae:

g1-g2

a-b

I keep on getting an error message, am I typing in the formula completely wrong?

All I want to do is take away one raster layer from the other, giving me a new raster output.

Comment: What is the error message you get when the SAGA part starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying several attempts the following successfully worked:

(a-b)